# Coordinate values arent stored in processing

Tags: java, coordinates, processing

I really have no idea why the x and y values wont go to the drawLines function

```
float x, x1, x2;
float y, y1, y2;
float rad; //radius
int lines = 30; //number of lines
int colorNumber = 1;

void setup() {
  background(#FFFFFF);
  size (800, 600);
  rad = 8;
}

void draw() {
}
```

This creates the three dots or vertices of the mathematical envelope

```
void mouseClicked() {
  float x = mouseX;
  float x1 = mouseX;
  float x2 = mouseX;
  float y = mouseY;
  float y1 = mouseY;
  float y2 = mouseY;
  if (colorNumber == 1) {
    fill(#9393ff);
    ellipse(x, y, rad, rad);
  } else if (colorNumber == 2) {
    fill(#FF9393);
    ellipse(x1, y1, rad, rad);
  } else if (colorNumber == 3) {
    fill(#93ff93);
    ellipse(x2, y2, rad, rad);
  }
}
```

This is supposed to draw the envelope using the coordinates of the vertices

```
void drawLines(int numLines) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i = i + 1) {
    float x = mouseX;
    float x1 = mouseX;
    float x2 = mouseX;
    float y = mouseY;
    float y1 = mouseY;
    float y2 = mouseY;
    float t = (float) i/(numLines-1); 
    float startX = x + t * (x1 - x);
    float startY = y + t * (y1 - y);
    float endX = x1 + t * (x2 - x1);
    float endY = y1 + t * (y2 - y1);
    line (startX, startY, endX, endY);
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  colorNumber++; 
  if (colorNumber == 4) {
    colorNumber = 1;
  }
  println(colorNumber);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyPressed == true) {
    background(#FFFFFF);
  }
}
```

this last stuff just tells the code if you press a key, it will reset the backround

Comment: It looks like you are shadowing the variables `x` and `y` - which ones do you want to to use - only declare them once? Although I have no idea from your code where the values `mouseX` etc are being set/declared

Comment: Well I have three coordinate pairs therefore 6 coordinate points (x,x1,x2,y,y1,y2) which are equal to the mouseX and mouseY values of each on of the three clicks respectively. you click a spot in the window and it creates a dot which is where mouseX and mouseY values come into play.

Comment: where is `drawLines` called from?  [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have called it from everywhere and it hasn't worked. As sad at it is I have been working on this for hours and can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: *I have called it from everywhere and it hasn't worked* so basically you have no idea?  Please share the **real** code that you are using - this code does not called `drawLines`  - Just noticed that you are using `processing` - correct?

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/uxyt9 and yes I am using processing

Comment: So now, give us some information as to what it is doing, what methods are being entered into? what is being printed? This is called debugging, which I believe you can do in `processing` - see https://debug.martinleopold.com/ - maybe you should `print` from `drawLines`

Comment: ok so its pretty much what I expected - all of the x and y variables are being changes because they are all mouseX and mousY - Im not sure how to make them still mouseX and mouseY but not to change the others.

Comment: Dylan, step back, relax and figure out what you really want to ask.  Your first statement *I really have no idea why the x and y values wont go to the drawLines function* is meaningless and unsupported by fact.  **State clearly** what you do not understand.  Also *Im not sure how to make them still mouseX and mouseY but not to change the others* is non-understandable

Comment: I have done some debugging of your code, this code `if (mousePressed == true) {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 8, 8);
    drawLines(30);
  }` is never executed.  Maybe I just do not know how to run your application, but I would change the logic to be `if the mouse is clicked 4 times then just the `dots`

Answer (score 0):

I understand your intention with using mouseX and mouseY to specify the coordinates of one of the 3 points of the envelope on click. The current issue is that **all 3 points are being set to the same coordinate** with each click. You need to introduce a variable to keep track of which coordinate to set on-click, such that only one pair is set. Then, only once all 3 coordinates are set, drawLines() can be called.

I propose the following:

Introduce 2 variables, one to keep track of which point is being modified; the other an array of PVectors (just to make it cleaner).

```
int index = 0;
PVector[] coords = new PVector[3];
```

Modify *mouseClicked()* to include the following:

```
void mouseClicked() {

    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 8, 8);
    coords[index] = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
    index += 1;
    if (index == 3) {
        drawLines(lines);
    }
    index %= 3;
}
```

*drawLines()* becomes:

```
void drawLines(int numLines) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i = i + 1) {
        x = coords[0].x;
        x1 = coords[1].x;
        x2 = coords[2].x;
        y = coords[0].y;
        y1 = coords[1].y;
        y2 = coords[2].y;
        float t = (float) i / (numLines - 1);
        float startX = x + t * (x1 - x);
        float startY = y + t * (y1 - y);
        float endX = x1 + t * (x2 - x1);
        float endY = y1 + t * (y2 - y1);
        line(startX, startY, endX, endY);
    }
}
```

Finally, since your drawing on a black background, and the default stroke colour is black, use strokeColour() to change the colour of the lines so that you can see the envelope once its drawn.